# git commit broken time zone

Tags: git, rebase, fsck

```
> git fsck
error in commit %hash%: invalid author/committer line - bad time zone

> git show %hash%
Date: Mon Mar 18 23:57:14 2201 -5274361
```

How this can be fixed? With `git rebase` in master branch and delete\update commit info, or do some magic in project `.git` directory, or somehow else?

Comment: Well rebasing and removing/updating the commit would result in a massive history rewrite which might not be preferrable. The most interesting part for me is how this error could happend? I don't have a answer yet.

Comment: What version of Git are you using? Do you use it in conjunction with any third-party tool?

Comment: Remote repo git version is 1.7, my (client) is 1.9, nothing else is used.

Comment: The important is what version of Git was used to create the guilty commit.

Comment: Can you run `git cat-file -p %hash%`?

Comment: `> git cat-file -p %brokenCommitHash%
    100644 blob hash1 filename1
    100644 blob hash2 filename2
    040000 tree hash3 dirname`

Sorry, cant get correct code formatting (

Comment: fastexport + fastimport the repo.. This is a crazy error.. But its clear your repo is brooken! :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go for the `git rebase -i` solution.

Edit the wrong commits and `git commit --amend --date="Mon Jul 24 14:00 2015 +0100"` when you stop on them.

If you rebase on pushed commits, you'll have to rewrite the branch history (in your case `master`) by doing a `push -f`.

Comment: I was able to amend the commits but git fsck shows the old ones are still there...

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: **If the rebase option does not work**.. I would write off trying to repair the repo..

I would go with a fast export and fast import..

```
git fast-export --all | (cd /cleanrepo/ && git fast-import)
```

I would add the `--anonymize` to remove all identifying info if the above fails..